# Does Alfresco 3.4e CE support clustering?

Tags: glassfish, alfresco, cluster-computing, jgroups

I have just a simple question to answer !

Does Alfresco 3.4e Community Edition support clustering ?

If yes, then what are the supported clustering methods (e.g is JGroups supported?) ?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work with Community, yes. There are a few little bits in Enterprise that'll make the setup and monitoring easier, which coupled with the support you get may mean you'd be better off going to Enterprise if you can.

You should probably start with [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/alfresco/06192008-high-availability-clustering-with-alfresco) to get you through the basics of Alfresco clustering. Once you've understood that, you likely want to read the Alfresco documentation on [Setting up high availability systems](http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fha-intro.html) which covers the concepts, initial cluster config, setting up JGroups etc.

You may also find it useful to read [this guide](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Cluster_Configuration_V2.1.3_and_Later) on the Alfresco Wiki for instructions on setting it up, including how to configure [JGroups](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Configuring_JGroups_and_Alfresco_Clusters) as part of that process, if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for answer, 
But I'm really follow that presentation & wiki, but I have a strange problems & exceptions, That make me wondering & asking this question about alfresco is support clustering, specially after I read "Enterprise" between parenthesis somewhere in alfresco wiki after "JGroups" configuration.

look @ :
http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=40252&p=118012#p118012
http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=40266&p=118031#p118031

Comment: I'd suggest you try it in something other than glassfish first, so you can be sure any issues aren't related to that. You may find the Alfresco documentation on [HA](http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fha-intro.html) easier to follow than the wiki.

Comment: It seems I'll , but I found the link that say (Enterprise) , http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_Configuration#What_Can_Be_Set.3F is that means JGroups not supported !

Comment: Alfresco Eng. say that JGroups for Enterprise: http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=40281